# How to report on the last day of each month SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What is the best way to run the report every month on the last day in report service web portal?

It seems pretty straightforward but I could not seem to find a direct way to do this.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2014/05/report-manager-subscription-last-day-of-month/

Answer (score 1):

Use "On week of month" instead of On calendar day(s).
Pick "Last", check all weekdays.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiyBQ.png)